# Best way to store templated constants in Java

Tags: java

I have 4 motors let's say, and for each, I have some constants like the ID, the maximum speed, and the minimum power. Let's say that at some point there are going to be many constants added to this `MotorConstants` class, and this is what it currently looks like:

```java
public abstract class MotorConstants{
  abstract final int ID;
  abstract final double MAX_SPEED, MIN_POWER;
}
// And an implementation:
public class LeftMotorConstants extends MotorConstants{
  final int ID = 3;
  final double MAX_SPEED = 500, MIN_POWER = 10;
}
```

I understand that abstract fields are not possible. What could be a good replacement for them?
I'm afraid of passing everything through the constructor/getters and setters because then after adding a field would take a lot of time and lots of lines of code, instead of the (not working) code sample.

Comment: abstract classes  can have constant fields; what is not possible is overriding them in a subclass.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Yep.
I'm talking about abstract _fields_, meaning that they force the subclass to implement them. I know this doesn't exist, I'm looking for a best practice.

Comment: Make it an `interface Motor` with methods like `double maxSpeed();` and then implement them in the concrete classes, returning whatever values. Your statement about "constructors/getters and setters" implies that for any "getter" there must be a be a corresponding backing field and setter, but of course that's not necessary.

Comment: *about abstract fields, meaning that they force the subclass to implement them* - there's a concept of *abstract fields* in TypeScript (and you might be familiar with it), but it's absolutely alien to Java. Because the ways of how classes work in these two languages are very different. I guess the approach of utilizing interfaces provided in the answer by @OneCricketeer is probably the most suitable way to translate this idea into Java.

Answer (score 1):

Constants cannot be inherited and then overwritten; that defeats the purpose of calling them "constant. Methods can be overridden to return differing values (even if they return an external constant variable).

If I understand your data model, and ID belongs to a specific instance of some "part". The other fields are also specific properties to some instance, which should not belong to the overall class, so that would be done with methods.

This is where you'd use interfaces to define those common "templates" that a class needs to implement.

E.g.

```
interface LimitedPower {
  double getMinPower();
}

interface LimitedSpeed {
  double getMaxSpeed();
}

interface Identifiable {
  int getId();
}

abstract class AbstractMotor implements Identifiable {
  protected int id; // available to all subclasses
 
  @Override
  public int getId() {
    return this.id;
  }
}

class LimitedMotor extends AbstractMotor implements LimitedSpeed, LimitedPower {
  private double minPower, maxSpeed;
  
  public LimitedMotor(int id, double minPower, double maxSpeed) { 
      this.id = id; 
      this.minPower = minPower; 
      this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed;
  } 

  // TODO: implement interface getter+setter functions
}

class MotorPowered {
  final AbstractMotor[] motors = new AbstractMotor[4];

  public MotorPowered(AbstractMotor left, AbstractMotor right, AbstractMotor top, AbstractMotor buttom) {
    this.motors[0] = left;
    //... etc
  }
}
```

Then, when you actually create a specific motor, you can pass in the details for it.

```
final AbstractMotor left = new LimitedMotor(3, 10, 500);
MotorPowered engine = new MotorPowered(left, ...);
```

If you want to say "all 'limited motors' will have the same id", then you can add some `final static int ID` to that class, and remove the constructor parameter.

```
class LimitedMotor extends AbstractMotor implements LimitedSpeed, LimitedPower {
  private double minPower, maxSpeed;
  
  public static final int ID = 3;

  public LimitedMotor(double minPower, double maxSpeed) { 
      this.id = LimitedMotor.ID; 
      this.minPower = minPower; 
      this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed;
  }
```

Comment: That's what I don't want to do, pass everything in the constructor, because then I would have 20 different parameters in the constructor.
I want to pass in the constructor a single object that contains all of the constants for the new instance.

Comment: That's also possible, but I suspect not everything is truly constant and if you have static constants, you don't need parameters for them, as shown, but you will need fields or methods to extract that data from any instances

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your suggestion
What should I do If I have multiple instances of some class, and each instance requires a lot of information in order to operate, how do I organize all of its constants in a fashion that won't require me to pass all 20 variables in the constructor, and not make me edit 10 lines to add a new constant?

Comment: I don't understand your question. That's not a problem unique to Java. You could put all those properties into a Map or `Properties` object, and pass just one of those as a constructor parameter. Then you only would need to edit one line to put data into the map, and add a getter/setter in the class that holds the map as a field